# Change react-bootstrap <Image /> size using props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am making Avatar component using react-bootstrap. I need to pass a string that can be "sm", "md" or "lg" to my Avatar component.

```
<Avatar size="md" />
```

And in that component I have to change size of my react-bootstrap `<Image />`.
How can I do it? I don't know how to pass this props to my css file (and don't think I need it).
It's my Avatar component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { string } from 'prop-types';
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

import './avatar.module.scss';

const Avatar = ({size}) => {
 return (
   <div className="avatar-component">
     <Image roundedCircle />
   </div>
 );
};

Avatar.propTypes = {
 size: string
};

Avatar.defaultProps = {
 size: 'md'
};

export default Avatar;
```

Comment: Looking at the react bootstrap docs it looks like your meant to control size by wrapping inside a Col.  IOW, instead of wrapping inside a div use a Col and pass size to this.

Answer (score 2):

React-bootstrap is based on a 12 cols grid. Your Image component has to be wrapped inside a Col component. The size of your Image is based on the number of bootstrap columns you want to assign to the Image.

For exemple below, on a "md" screen size, you have by default 2 columns. You can similarly assign any number you want for each screen size (sm, lg...) :

```
import React from 'react';
import { string } from 'prop-types';
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

import './avatar.module.scss';

const Avatar = ({size}) => {
 return (
   <Col md={size} className="avatar-component">
     <Image roundedCircle src={/* your file path */} />
   </Col>
 );
};

Avatar.propTypes = {
 size: number
};

Avatar.defaultProps = {
 size: 2
};

export default Avatar;
```